# Nyquist diagram not encircle the origin

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

Given the function: $\frac{s-5}{s^2-4s +5}$

The function have one zero and two poles in the RHP. So according to principle of argument (or Nyquist diagram), the Nyquist plot encircle the origin N = |Z-P| = |1-2| = 1 time. But the Nyquist plot does not show that:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to do.

When you apply the argument principle, the contour must not pass through any of the poles or zeros.

In this case, $g(s)= {s-5 \over s^2-4s+5}$ has a zero at infinity and so the curve 'passes' through zero.

Since you are interested in the difference of right half plane poles & zeros, the contour can be modified to be $0 \to iR$, then $R e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta$ going from ${\pi \over 2}$ to $-{\pi \over 2}$ and then from $-iR$ back to zero, for some large $R$. If $R$ is sufficiently large, then the curve will pass to the right of
$0$.

Note that the winding number of the right half plane poles & zeros is $-1$ with
this curve, and the contour had a winding number of $+1$ around the origin, so the argument principle tells us that
$1 = \sum_{z} \eta(z, \gamma) -\sum_{p} \eta(p, \gamma) = \#\text{poles} - \#\text{zeroes}$.

**However**...

If you are trying to apply the Nyquist stability criterion to $g$, then
you are trying to determine the stability of the closed loop transfer function ${g \over 1+g}$ where $g$ is the open loop transfer function (assuming unity feedback). In this case, the system is stable if $1+g$ has no right half plane **zeros**.

So, either plot $1+g$ and count encirclements of zero, or plot $g$ and count encirclement of $-1$.

If this is what you are trying to go then the issue of passing through zero does not arise here.

Comment: I mean that I want to check the argument principle: plot g and count encirclement of origin. From the numbers of zeros and poles in the RHP, then the Nyquist plot must encircle zero 1 times, but Nyquist plot does not show this. According to your answer, the curve pass through the zero at infinity, but all of the examples I have seen always have zeros at infinity and people still use curves that pass through infinity to draw Nyquist plot

Comment: The nyquist plot usually looks for encirclements of $-1$, not zero. The argument principal involves a closed curve in the complex plane.

Comment: I understand the encirclements of -1, the nyquist plot usually looks for encirclements of −1 but I want to look for encirclements of zero because I want to check the argumetn principal. What I mean here is: Given a function and a path that encircles entire RHP (I call this path 1), the path that is mapped from path 1 through the function is called path 2. According to the argument principal, the number of encirclement  of origin of path 2 is Z - P, with Z and P are the number of zeros and poles inside path 1, respectively.

Comment: I think I get it: path 1 must not pass through zero